# Meteor JS custom login (TypeError: Illegal invocation)

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I've followed along with this guide to create a custom login/registration form on my Meteor app: http://blog.benmcmahen.com/post/41741539120/building-a-customized-accounts-ui-for-meteor

meteor: **1.1.3**
meteor-platform: **1.2.0**
accounts-base: **1.1.2**
accounts-password: **1.0.4**

Everything seems to be working correctly, the user **is logged in** after form submission. However this exception is being thrown (client console):

```
Exception in queued task: TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77c0809654ee3a10dcd5a4f961fb1437e7957d33:2789:16
    at Spacebars.call (http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?3c496d2950151d744a8574297b46d2763a123bdf:169:18)
    at Spacebars.mustacheImpl (http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?3c496d2950151d744a8574297b46d2763a123bdf:106:25)
    at Object.Spacebars.mustache (http://localhost:3000/packages/spacebars.js?3c496d2950151d744a8574297b46d2763a123bdf:110:39)
    at HTML.P.class (http://localhost:3000/client/views/common/template.header.js?f939d857d5e7089d2f50b9b4b0358c8148c885f9:91:48)
    at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77c0809654ee3a10dcd5a4f961fb1437e7957d33:2029:12)
    at Blaze._HTMLJSExpander.def.visitAttribute (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77c0809654ee3a10dcd5a4f961fb1437e7957d33:1958:21)
    at HTML.TransformingVisitor.def.visitAttributes (http://localhost:3000/packages/htmljs.js?539b5fc23cf5e63bc8e324543a1026b138316a8c:228:44)
    at Blaze._HTMLJSExpander.def.visitAttributes (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77c0809654ee3a10dcd5a4f961fb1437e7957d33:1952:63)
    at Object.Blaze._expandAttributes (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77c0809654ee3a10dcd5a4f961fb1437e7957d33:1981:32)
```

### Login Template

```
<template name="login">
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <div>
    <form id="loginForm" action="action">
      <label>Email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="loginEmail" />
      <label>Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="loginPassword" />
      <input type="submit" id="loginSubmit" value="Login" />
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

### Login Events

```
Template.login.events = {
  'submit #loginForm': function(event,f){
    event.preventDefault();

    // retrieve input values
    var email = f.find('#loginEmail').value,
        password = f.find('#loginPassword').value;

    if (isValidPassword(password) && isNotEmpty(email) && isEmail(email)){

      Meteor.loginWithPassword(email,password,function(error){
        if(error){
          console.log('Login Attempt Failed. \nError: ',error);
          flash(error.reason,'error');
        }
        else {
          flash('Welcome back!',alert);
        }
      });  
    } 
    else {
      flash('Invalid email or password.', 'error');
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to get rid of it?

**----Edit----**
Still no luck - I've tried this tutorial as well: http://meteortips.com/tutorial/custom-registration-form/ but am seeing the same issue

**---- Edit #2 ----**
Fixed it! The exception goes off *after* the login has occurred from the line:
`flash('Welcome back!',alert);`
 I forgot to put alert in quotes. -_- This took care of it:

```
flash('Welcome back!',"alert");
```

Comment: This might be dull question, but what do you mean by meteor: 1.1.3? I have accounts-password@1.0.4 and meteor-platform@1.2.0 and Meteor 1.0. I don't get this Exception. Did you try to run Meteor.loginWithPassword to run synchronously?

Comment: Under .meteor/versions it says meteor@1.1.3. I was under the impression that Meteor 1.0 was the latest release... am I looking at the wrong file?

Comment: Ah ok - that sounds good. I'm running the same versions - no issues. I'm on Mac OS 10.10 w Safari/Chrome/Firefox. My code is slightly different but that shouldn't matter. Can you run an isolated test in a new meteor project?

Comment: Hey Steffo, turns out it was a typo after all. flash("Welcome back!", "alert") needed to be in quotes. :) Thank you for your help, I appreciate it!